# What is the distribution of $\chi^n_k$?

Tags: distributions, probability, stochastic-processes

$\chi^n_k=\sum_{i=1}^kx_i^n$ where $x_i$ are Gaussian variables and $n>2$?

Comment: your gaussian variables are iid ?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  A name?  A simple formula for the density?

Comment: yes , they are iid

Answer (score 3):

well, as a bound, if $n$ is even, $\chi_k^n$ will be bounded from below by a Chi-square, and $(\chi_k^n)^{1/n}$ should be bounded from above by the maximum of $k$ half-normals, or thereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(10); x <- matrix(rnorm(15000), ncol=15)
plot(density(rowSums(x^2)), col=2, xlim=c(-100, 100))
for (i in 3:10) {
   lines(density(rowSums(x^i)), col=i)
}
```

Can give us a plot.

I don't have the perfect theoretical results.

Another thing is, what's will it be if $n$ is not an integer?

For example, what is $(-3.5)^{3.4}$?

Oh, maybe you're looking for this [article](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/pdf_extract/46/3-4/296)?